# Java Swing: GridBagContraints not formatting properly

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I've been working on this program in CS class and I'm not sure why GridBagLayout, or GridBagConstraints, is not working properly.

Right now, I'm trying to get these labels to align like they should (according to this Java book anyway) but they don't do much of anything at the moment.

Any help would be appreciated.

[What it displays right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZZJt.png)

My code:

```
public class Main {
     private static final int WIDTH = 1920, HEIGHT = 1080;
     private Database database = new Database();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Swing GUI
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel formPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JLabel header = new JLabel();
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
    mainPanel.add(formPanel);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;

    header.setText("First Name: ");

    formPanel.add(header, gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;

    formPanel.add(new JLabel("Last Name: "));
    gbc.gridy++;

    formPanel.add(new JLabel("Email: "));
    gbc.gridy++;

    formPanel.add(new JLabel("Username: "));
    gbc.gridy++;

    formPanel.add(new JLabel("Password: "));
    gbc.gridy++;
    }

}
```

Comment: `formPanel.add(new JLabel("Last Name: "));` ... you forget to include the constraints, `formPanel.add(new JLabel("Last Name: "), gbc);` - Constraints are bound to a specific object (one-to-one relationship), but `GridBagLayout` makes a copy of the constraints when you add a component to it, so it's safe to continue modifying the instance of the constraints you have

Comment: Oh damn, forgot about that. Do you know why "gbc.anchor"  doesn't effect anything? I put "gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;" before I added the header but none of the text moves to the top left.

Comment: Mostly because `GridBagLayout`, by default, layouts it's content out around the centre of the component, so it's likely all the text is been aligned, top/left in the cell they are in